# Separation of concerns in d3.js + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I'm making a project to help learning [graph theory](https://github.com/hlucasfranca/graphe/) and I'm having problems in the separation of concerns of the directives which uses d3.js to draw the SVG on the screen. The following directive code handles the svg drawing on the screen(summarized for brevity).

```
angular.module('graphe.directives')
.directive('gpStage', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/gpStage.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        require: '^gpContainer',
        controller: 'gpStageCtrl',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, gpContainerCtrl) {                
            var selectedNode = null,
                selectedLink = null,
                nodeGroup;

            // init svg
            var outer = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg:svg') 
                // a lot of code....

            outer.append('defs').append('marker')
                // a lot of code....

            var xLines, yLines;
            var gridSize = 20;
            var gridWidth = 2000;
            var gridHeight = 2000;

            var vis = outer.append('svg:g')
                // a lot of code....
                ;

            drawGrid();

            vis.append('svg:rect')
                // a lot of code....

            // init force layout
            var force = d3.layout.force()
                .size([scope.width, scope.height])
                .nodes(scope.graph.nodeList)
                .links(scope.graph.linkList)
                .on('tick', tick);

            // get layout properties
            var nodes = force.nodes(),
                links = force.links(),
                // group all links
                link = vis.append('g').attr('id','link-group').selectAll('.link'),
                node = vis.append('g').selectAll('.node');

            redraw();

            function tick() {
               // a lot of code....
            }

            function rescale() {
                // a lot of code....
            }

            // redraw force layout
            function redraw() {
                outer
                    .attr('width' , scope.stageWidth)
                    .attr('height', scope.stageHeight);

                link = link.data(links);

                link.enter().append('line');                   
                link.exit().remove();
                node = node.data(nodes);

                nodeGroup = node.select('g')
                    .attr('id', function(d,i){ return 'node-' + i; });

                node.select('.node circle')
                    .attr('fill', function (d) { return d.color; } );

                node.select('.node text')
                    .text(function(d){ return d.label; });

                nodeGroup = node.enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('id', function(d,i){ return 'node-' + i; });

                nodeGroup.attr('class', 'node').append('circle');

                node.exit().remove();                    

                function dragMove (d, i) {} // a lot of code....

                function dragStart(d,i){ } // a lot of code....

                function dragEnd(d,i){ }

                var nodeDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
                    .on('drag', dragMove)
                    .on("dragstart", dragStart)
                    .on("dragend", dragEnd);

                nodeGroup.call(nodeDrag);
                nodeGroup.on('click',mousedownnode);

                function mousedownnode(d) { }
                node.exit().remove();
                force.start();
            }

            function collide(alpha) { }

            scope.$watch('stageWidth', redraw);
            scope.$watch('stageHeight', redraw);
            scope.$watch('graph', redraw, true);
            scope.$watch('currentOption', function () {});
        }
    };
})
// For communication with other directives
.controller('gpStageCtrl',function ($scope) {        

    $scope.selectNode = selectNode;
    $scope.selectLink = selectLink;
    $scope.deselectLink = deselectLink;
    $scope.deselectNode = deselectNode;   

    function selectNode (id) { }
    function selectLink (source, target){ }
    function deselectLink (source, target){ }
    function deselectNode (id){ }
});
```

Is there any better way to separate the concerns of d3.js SVG drawing?

Edit: [The running code.](http://hlucasfranca.github.io/tests/#/graph)

Comment: Seems like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit

Comment: Asked, thanks! I'm a newbie on Stack Exchange community :).